# PHP - asynchronous foreach loop

Tags: php, asynchronous, foreach

I have a website that is separating music tracks, but to do so the user should have credits bought in a subscription.

My issue is when a user has for example 2 credits left from a subscription and uploads 3 tracks, my script loops through the tracks and sees that there is valid credits and starts all of them at once and moves the users available credits to a negative number.

I need to go through the loop asynchronously so that each track has the opportunity to deduct the credits necessary before going through the next one and it thinking it still has credits.

Below is my full script with the issue, I've added a few comments to explain what is happening:

```
// i first query my db for tracks that are valid and loop through them
$status = 'validated';
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM demixer.tracks WHERE status=:status");
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $status);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $row){
    $track_id = $row['id'];
    echo $track_id.' '.$status.'<br>';
    $account_id = $row['account_id'];
    $length = $row['length'];
    $separation_type = $row['separation_type'];
    $separation_algorithm = $row['separation_algorithm'];
    $upload_id = $row['upload_id'];
    $timings = unserialize($row['timings']);
    
    $length_in_minutes = $length/60;
    
    if($separation_type == 'trial' || $separation_type == 'preview'){
        // if the track is a trial i don't have an issue because it doesn't take any credits
    }else{
        $sub_array = [];
        $valid_sub_array = [];
        $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        
        // i get an array of valid subscriptions
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM demixer.subscriptions WHERE account_id=:account_id AND date_expires>:now");
        $stmt->bindParam(':account_id', $account_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':now', $now);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $key=>$row){
            $sub_array[$key] = $row;
        }
        //if its empty i don't have an issue
        if(!empty($sub_array)){
            $i = 0;
            foreach($sub_array as $row){
                $subscription_id = $row['id'];
                $no_songs = $row['no_songs'];
                $no_minutes = $row['no_minutes'];
                $date_expires = $row['date_expires'];
                
                //each subscription has credits for X amount of songs (no_songs) and up to Y length in minutes (no_minutes), when a credit from a subscription is used it is added to the 'subscriptions_used' table in my db, this is the part that needs to be done before looping through to the next track otherwise the credits have not been taken away yet
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM demixer.subscriptions_used WHERE subscription_id=:subscription_id");
                $stmt->bindParam(':subscription_id', $subscription_id);
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $row){
                    $no_used = $row['COUNT(*)'];
                }
                if($no_songs>$no_used){
                    if($length_in_minutes<$no_minutes){
                        echo 'this subscription has credits<br />';
                        $valid_sub_array[$i]['sub_id'] = $subscription_id;
                        $valid_sub_array[$i]['no_minutes'] = $no_minutes;
                        $valid_sub_array[$i]['date_expires'] = $date_expires;
                        $i++;
                    }else{
                        $message = 'Demixer only supports tracks up to 10 minutes (600 seconds), please try again with a shorter track';
                        $status = 'error';
                        
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE demixer.tracks SET status=:status, message=:message WHERE id=:track_id");
                        $stmt->bindParam(':status', $status);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':message', $message);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':track_id', $track_id);
                        $stmt->execute();
                    }
                }else{
                    $message = 'You need to buy more credits';
                    $status = 'error';
                    
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE demixer.tracks SET status=:status, message=:message WHERE id=:track_id");
                    $stmt->bindParam(':status', $status);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':message', $message);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':track_id', $track_id);
                    $stmt->execute();
                }
            }
        }else{
            $message = 'You need to buy more credits';
            $status = 'error';
            
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE demixer.tracks SET status=:status, message=:message WHERE id=:track_id");
            $stmt->bindParam(':status', $status);
            $stmt->bindParam(':message', $message);
            $stmt->bindParam(':track_id', $track_id);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        
        array_multisort(array_column($valid_sub_array, 'no_minutes'), SORT_ASC, array_column($valid_sub_array, 'date_expires'), SORT_ASC, $valid_sub_array);
        var_dump($valid_sub_array);
        
        if(!empty($valid_sub_array)){
            $subscription_to_use = $valid_sub_array[0]['sub_id'];
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO demixer.subscriptions_used (track_id, subscription_id) VALUES (:track_id, :subscription_id)");
            $stmt->bindParam(':track_id', $track_id);
            $stmt->bindParam(':subscription_id', $subscription_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            
            echo 'start full<br />';
            
            $data = array(
                'separationAlgorithm' => $separation_algorithm,
                'uploadId' => $upload_id,
                'outputFormats' => array('mp3')
            );
            $payload = json_encode($data);
            
            $request = curl_init($api_url.'separation/start');
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:'.$token));
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            
            $response = curl_exec($request);
            $errors = curl_error($request);
            $httpcode = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($request);
            
            if(!empty($errors)){
                echo $httpcode.' '.$errors;
            }else{
                echo $httpcode.' '.$response;
            }
            echo '<br />';
            
            $decoded_response = (array)json_decode($response);
            $separation_id = $decoded_response['separationId'];
            
            $start_separation = date(DATE_RFC822);
            $timings['start_separation'] = $start_separation;
            $timings = serialize($timings);
            
            $status = 'processing';
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE demixer.tracks SET status=:status, separation_id=:separation_id, timings=:timings WHERE id=:track_id");
            $stmt->bindParam(':status', $status);
            $stmt->bindParam(':separation_id', $separation_id);
            $stmt->bindParam(':timings', $timings);
            $stmt->bindParam(':track_id', $track_id);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could subtract the credits for all the tracks before actually separating the tracks. This will also prevent any problems you could have when an user submits multiple sets of tracks in multiple browser windows. Users will try this, if processing takes time. In case of an error no tracks will be returned and you can refund the credits taken. Your code can be improved in many ways. To get suggestions you could upload your code to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Make sure your code is working correctly, and add some more comments, before you do so.

Comment: Similarly to the suggestion above, but a bit more advanced, would be to "reserve" credits for the current job of separating tracks. The credits will only be really subtracted when a job has been completed successfully. This method is less fragile because, even when the job crashes horribly, the credits will still belong to the user.